# Links from navigation bar are doubling up on each other

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, menu, hyperlink, navigation

Here is an example of my code:

```
<div class="col_1">
            <a href="Shower-Faucets/"><img src="../product_images/shower_head.jpg"/><p >Shower Faucets</p></a href>
        </div>

        <div class="col_1">
            <a href="Bar-faucets/"><img src="../product_images/bar_faucet.jpg"/><p >Bar faucets</p></a href>
        </div>
```

when i go to one link from the navagation bar the links stack up which breaks the link.

Example of whats happening:

www.Website.com  
www.Website.com/Shower-Faucets/ 
www.Website.com/Shower-Faucets/Bar-faucets/

Example of what should happen:

www.Website.com > 
www.Website.com/Shower-Faucets/ > 
www.Website.com/Bar-faucets/

Comment: Is there CSS/JS applied to this nav bar?  Any reason you aren't using an unadorned and unordered list for your navigation items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add a '/' to the beginning of your href's.  This will make the links based off of your address.

```
<a href="/Shower-Faucets">
<a href="/Bar-faucets">
```

Without the backslash the url appears to be relative to the location that you are currently at, hence the stacking of the address.

Comment: I have to wait a few minutes